# Find gap in datetime range with Linq to sql in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like use linq to sql to query (prefer vb.net but c# example will do  a table for records that are grouped by a field in the table and have holes in the datetime field that are greater than 30 minutes. My table has records added at regular intervals during the lifetime of a job generally every two minutes occasionally there is a period of missing records. The table holds records for multiple jobs in the same date range although I have only added one with a different job number to highlight this. The table looks like the table below.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
VB .NET, untested:

```
Dim jobs = New List(Of Job)() From {
        New Job() With {
            .Date = New DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            .JobGroup = 1,
            .Value = 100
        },
        New Job() With {
            .Date = New DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0),
            .JobGroup = 1,
            .Value = 200
        },
        New Job() With {
            .Date = New DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0),
            .JobGroup = 1,
            .Value = 300
        },
        New Job() With {
            .Date = New DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0),
            .JobGroup = 2,
            .Value = 600
        },
        New Job() With {
            .Date = New DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 40, 0, 0),
            .JobGroup = 1,
            .Value = 400
        },
        New Job() With {
            .Date = New DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 42, 0, 0),
            .JobGroup = 1,
            .Value = 500
        },
        New Job() With {
            .Date = New DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0),
            .JobGroup = 2,
            .Value = 700
        },
        New Job() With {
            .Date = New DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 49, 0, 0),
            .JobGroup = 2,
            .Value = 800
        }
    }

    Dim gaps = jobs.OrderBy(Function(x) x.JobGroup).Skip(1).Zip(jobs, Function(c, p) New With {Key
        .Current = c, Key
        .Previous = p, Key
        .Gap = (c.Date - p.Date).TotalMinutes
    }).Where(Function(x) x.Gap >= 30 AndAlso (x.Current.JobGroup = x.Previous.JobGroup))

    For Each gap In gaps
        Console.WriteLine($"Job Group: {gap.Current.JobGroup}, Gap (minutes): {gap.Gap}, Value: {gap.Current.Value} ")
    Next
End Sub

Class Job
    Public Property JobGroup As Integer
    Public Property Date As DateTime
    Public Property Value As Integer
End Class
```

I´m a bit rusty at VB so I´ll give you an C# answer like you said.

```
 //Sample Data                                              //Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond
 var jobs = new List<Job>() { new Job() { Date = new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), JobGroup = 1 ,Value = 100},
                               new Job() { Date =  new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0),JobGroup = 1 ,Value = 200} ,
                               new Job() { Date =  new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0),JobGroup = 1 ,Value = 300},
                               new Job() { Date =  new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), JobGroup = 2 ,Value = 600},
                               new Job() { Date =  new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 40, 0, 0),JobGroup = 1 ,Value = 400},
                               new Job() { Date =  new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 42, 0, 0), JobGroup = 1 ,Value = 500},
                               new Job() { Date =  new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), JobGroup = 2 ,Value = 700},
                               new Job() { Date =  new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 1, 49, 0, 0), JobGroup = 2 ,Value = 800}
        };

 //Determine gaps
 var gaps = jobs.OrderBy(x => x.JobGroup) //don´t mix job group IDs
                 .Skip(1) //To compare current and previous job record
                 .Zip(jobs, (c, p) => new { Current = c, Previous = p, Gap = (c.Date - p.Date).TotalMinutes }) //Determine gap between current and previous record
                 .Where(x => x.Gap >= 30 && (x.Current.JobGroup == x.Previous.JobGroup)); //Only take those gaps which are GT 30 minutes

 foreach(var gap in gaps)
 {
   Console.WriteLine($"Job Group: {gap.Current.JobGroup}, Gap (minutes): {gap.Gap}, Value: {gap.Current.Value} ");
 }

 //Result:
 //Job Group: 1, Gap(minutes): 36, Value: 400
 //Job Group: 2, Gap(minutes): 40, Value: 800
```

My sample data is just a simple DTO

```
class Job
{
    public int JobGroup { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: PO stated `(prefer vb.net but c# example will do)`. And since VB .NET *is* C# at CIL level and there a pleny of translation tools I don´t see a huge problem here... but anyway I don´t want to upset anybody here.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply's I will let you know how they work for me. Cheers!

Comment: So sorry, didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that @Alex B's solution requires the table be pulled into memory before executing because .Zip isn't translatable to SQL. in this case, you may want to look into doing this via a view leveraging [SQL's Lag...Over syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and just consume the results of that via a Linq to SQL Entity. Something like:

```sql
CREATE VIEW vwJobGaps AS
SELECT Job, DateAdded, PrevDateAdded, Value,
DATEDIFF(m, PrevDateAdded, DateAdded) As MinutesFromLastJob
FROM
    (SELECT Job, DateAdded, Value,
        LAG(DateAdded, 1, null) over (Partition by Job order by DateAdded ASC) As PrevDateAdded
    FROM MYTable))
```

And then for your entity:

```
<Table("vwJobGaps")>
Public Class JobGap
  Public Property Job As Integer
  Public Property DateAdded As DateTime
  Public Property PrevDateAdded As DateTime
  Public Property Value As Decimal
  Public Property MinutesFromLastJob As Integer
End Class
```

Since you're using a view here, you can add additional filters, joins, etc using standard LINQ to SQL just as you would other tables:

```
var query = from gap in dc.JobGaps
            where gap.MinutesFromLastJob > 30
            '' select clause not needed in vb
```

Comment: That´s a fair point. But a `.ToList()` right before my `.Zip` would do it. If PO is dealing with mass data he should filter in DB early anyway.

Comment: If the filter requires the time between items, then you can't put the filter before the zip.

Comment: You could filter on day e,g., than the gaps in memory

Comment: True. It might be good to add that kind of filtering to your answer.